# Is there a way to only accept specific file NAMES be uploaded rather than file TYPES?

Tags: forms

I'm trying to create a basic button that will only accept the upload of files (.pdf .doc etc) with a certain file NAME. I understand the restrictions that can be put on the file TYPE but would like to have more control over the file NAME. If anyone can show me a way using HTML/CSS/Javascript or more, that would be fantastic! Thanks

I would like an error message to appear if the file NAME isn't something specific

Comment: I was going to suggest using some simple JS to determine if the name of the chosen file matches what you want, but that would only work after the fact, and you probably want the file selection box to show only the files that match, is that right? I'm not sure that can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MrLister  . I have tried that approach with JS but it wasn't quite the result I was looking for. Maybe another way of explaining it is: Is there anyway of telling JS "do not upload if the file does not have X in the filename" I've looked all over but i think you may be right....It can't be done  :(

Answer (score 1):

You can start by checking the name and viewing fileInput.files[0], also consider rgex expressions

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");

fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (fileInput.files[0].name == "FILENAME.pdf") {
      //handle the file result
      console.log(fileInput.files[0]);
    } else {
      throw new Error(fileInput.files[0].name + " is not a valid filename")
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
```